# Find $\sum_{n \ge 1} 1/n^2$ using the Fourier expansion of $f(x) = x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-series

The strategy I have been asked to take, is to show that Fourier coefficients of the function $f(x) = x$ on $[0, 1]$ are up
to a constant equal to $1/n^2$.Then I should apply the norm

\begin{equation*}
\lVert f \rVert_2 = (\int_0^1 \lvert f(x)\rvert^2 dx)^{1/2}
\end{equation*}

in terms of Fourier coefficients.

So I know that for an inner product space we have that

\begin{equation*}
x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x, e_n \rangle e_n
\end{equation*}

and the space we seem to be working in is $L^2 [0,1]$.

The first difficulty I am having is finding an orthonormal sequence in this space. Without some$(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ to work with. I cannot see how I can progress with this solution and I am not sure how to come up with an infinite linearly independent set of functions.

Comment: With Fourier series over $[0,1]$, the orthonormal sequence is taken to be $e^{2\pi i n x}$ for $n\in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: @GEdgar fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Omnomnomnom's choice:

Complete orthonormal set $e_n(x):=e^{2\pi i n x}$ on $[0,1]$.  For function
$f(x) := x$, the Fourier coefficients are
$$
c_n = \langle f,e_n\rangle = \int_0^1 x e^{-2\pi i n x}\;dx = \frac{i}{2\pi n}
,\qquad{n \ne 0}
\\
c_0 = \langle f,e_0\rangle = \int_0^1 x\;dx = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Then compute
$$
\|f\|^2 = \int_0^1 |x|^2\,dx = \frac{1}{3}
$$
So by Parseval's identity
$$
\|f\|^2 = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} |c_n|^2
\\
\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{4} + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4\pi^2n^2}
\\
\frac{\pi^2}{6} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let we consider $f(x)=x$ on $I=(-\pi,\pi)$.

$f$ is an odd function in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, hence its Fourier series is given by:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} c_n \sin(nx) \tag{1}$$
where integration by parts gives:
$$ c_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx = \frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\tag{2}$$ 
hence, by Parseval's identity,
$$ \frac{2\pi^3}{3}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)^2\,dx = \pi\sum_{n\geq 1}c_n^2 = 4\pi\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}\tag{3}$$
and simplifying:
$$ \zeta(2)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}.\tag{4}$$

Have also a look at one of the greatest question of all time: [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2).